# how to extract every element of repeated group in regex

Tags: python, regex

A string contains digits split by '-' or '_', how can I get every digits in the string?

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'\w(\d+)(?:(?:-|_)(\d+))*\w')

str='a1-2-3_4bc2-3_4d'
m = re.findall(pattern, str)
print(m)
```

I expect the output is [(1,2,3,4),(2,3,4)], but it gives [('1', '4'), ('2', '4')]

Comment: Why not just split on `[-_]` or `re.findall('\d+', str)`?

Comment: My real question is more complex, I just want to find a method to get all elements in a group

Comment: Even with your updated version. `re.findall('\d+', str)` still works. You need to update a version that reveals your real question.

Comment: I have updated the question, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: this answer is based on what was posted.

you almost got it, try `(\d+)(?:(?:-|_)(\d+))*?`

```
*?      # (zero or more)(lazy)
```

Comment: Thanks, but if pattern is \w(\d+)(?:(?:-|_)(\d+))*?\w'), str is a1-2-3_4b, your solution returns 1,3, but i still want 1,2,3,4

Comment: then maybe your should edit your question and clarify it more.

Answer (score 1):

You're already using findall, so you can simplify your regex to this:

```
(\d+)(?:-|_)?
```

In your full example you'll get

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)(?:-|_)?')

str='1-2-3_4'
m = re.findall(pattern, str)
print(m)
```

This returns

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Now, if you are going to throw letters in the mix, you might as well go super simple and extract all the numbers:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(\d+)')

str='1-2-3_4b5'
m = re.findall(pattern, str)
print(m)
```

That will give you

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

But obviously, that's a different match than taking - and _ into account

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely this can be done in a single step, which requires capturing variable numbers of group at the same time; You could try this instead:

```
import re
s='a1-2-3_4bc2-3_4d'

[re.findall(r'\d+', g.group()) for g in re.finditer(r'[\d_-]+', s)]
# [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4']]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is still not absolutely clear what the variations of the input string might be, but, given the sample string from the question, you can extract the digits this way:

- split by two consecutive non-digit characters (`\D{2}` - where `\D` would match a non-digit character) using [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)
- extract numbers from every match

Demo:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: s = 'a1-2-3_4bc2-3_4d'

In [3]: [re.findall(r"\d+", item) for item in re.split(r"\D{2}", s)]
Out[3]: [['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['2', '3', '4']]
```